# Trying to reset a list before filtering, but having trouble with the asynchronous states

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i have a const with an array of objects, named "data", a state that receive that data so I can update the screen when I change it, and I have a function that filter that data.

Every time that the user change the state of an HTML select, I trigger a function named handleChange that calls the filter function, so the user user can see the filtered content.
The problem is that I want to reset the state that receives the data, with the original data before filtering it, so if the user change one of the selects, it filter based on the original data, not the previous changed one, but when I try to update the state with the const data value, it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
  const [list, setList] = useState<IData[]>([...data]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<IFilter>({
    name: "",
    color: "",
    date: "",
  });

  function handleChange(
    key: keyof IData,
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: string }>
  ): void {
    const newFilter = { ...filter };
    newFilter[key as keyof IData] = event.target.value;
    setList([...data]); // reset the data
    setFilter({ ...newFilter }); // set the filter value
    filterList();
  }



  function filterList(): void {
    const keys = Object.keys(filter) as Array<keyof IData>;

    keys.forEach((key: keyof IData) => {
      if (filter[key]) {
        const newList = list.filter((item: IData) => item[key] === filter[key]);
        setList([...newList]);
      }
    });
  }
```

the problem is here

```
    setList([...data]); // reset the data
    setFilter({ ...newFilter }); // set the filter value
    filterList();
```

apparently, when the filterList happens, the list state is not yet restarted with the data value, since if I console log it inside filterList(), it return me only the list that was previous filtered. Is there a way for me to make sure that the setList happens before filtering, so I'm sure that the list that is filtered is always based on the initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the updated values inside `useEffect` ([more about useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)), so instead of calling `filterList()` directly inside the handler you move it inside the hook:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{filterList();},[list,filter])
```

Alternatively, you can pass the values as parameters to the function, after you updated the state with them

```
filterList(newList, newFilter)
```

UPDATE
As you update `list` inside `filterList` you'll need some sort of a flag to indicate if you need to filter of not (I'd use `useRef`). Note that it would be preferable to pass parameters into `filterList` instead, because this way there will be one less rendering cycle. Here is a simplified example of how both can work, let me know if they make sense : https://jsfiddle.net/6xoeqkr3/

Comment: since I gotta update the list inside filterList, if I use list as a dependency inside useEffect, I get a infinity loop. If try to do it without the list dependency, the result is the same, list is not updated with the default value. Using the states as parameters, doesn't help, because I need to update the states as well

Comment: Try just putting `filter` in the dependency array. Instead of `list.filter()` try `data.filter()`

Comment: if put filter in the dependency array, the result is still the same, with no change at all. The list is still setting the data. Since I have more than one select, if I do data.filter(), only the last filter value is considered, while the other filters are ignored

Comment: @Sku apologies, missed the fact that `filterList` updates `list` again. Have a look at the update